# Waiting till the particular message is displayed on console

Tags: vbscript

Here is my VBS code

```
Set wshshell = wscript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Wshshell.run "C:\Temp\Executable.exe -c -dir C:\Productdir"
'Wait till "This will install the product on your computer. Press OK, Cancel" appears
WScript.Sleep 10000
WshShell.SendKeys "~"
```

1. Is it possible "rather than hard-coded sleep of 10 secs" to add something like this for e.g. `if consolemessage="This will install the product on your computer. Press OK, Cancel" then WshShell.SendKeys "~"`?
2. Can `WScript.StdOut` be used to capture the console messages in the above case? I was not able to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can read [`StdOut`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cbxxzwb5%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) of a process when you execute the program using the [`Exec`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ateytk4a%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) method.

```
Set wshshell = wscript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set p = Wshshell.Exec("C:\Temp\Executable.exe -c -dir C:\Productdir")

Do While p.Status = 0
  output = ""
  Do Until p.StdOut.AtEndOfStream
    c = p.StdOut.Read(1)
    WScript.StdOut.Write c  'write read characters to the command prompt
    output = output & c
    If InStr(output, "This will install the product") > 0 Then
      'do stuff
      Exit Do
    End If
  Loop
  WScript.Sleep 100
Loop
```

Comment: thank again. I used ur logic but then now the installation is not getting started and the cursor waits for ever. As soon as I run this script now, this message is displayed "Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.8
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved." and then it waits endlessly.

Comment: The problem is that script is waiting for the `Set p = Wshshell.Exec("...")` line to finish before continuing to the `Do` loop.

Comment: @aphoria Wrong. `Exec` is running the command asynchronously.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers You are correct. I tried running you script (removing the `IF` inside the loop) using `CHOICE.EXE` and it didn't work...must be something weird with `CHOICE.EXE`. I tried again using `PSLIST.EXE` and it worked.

Comment: @aphoria `ReadLine` reads up to the next linefeed character and is blocking until then. `choice` doesn't print a newline unless you pressed a valid key. You should be able to avoid this gotcha by reading one character at a time in a loop (`.Read(1)`).

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers: I tried ur code with output & p.StdOut.Read(1) originally but then changed a bit to  output = output & p.StdOut.ReadLine. the problem continues. 1) Now nothing is displayed on the console, the screen is blank with the cursor blinking on. 2) In the section following do stuff, I am just writing this line wshshell.SendKeys "1". While debugging, the variable output has the values "This will install the product" but on the screen nothing appears. Meanwhile while debugging,  the execution of this wshshell.SendKeys "1", writes  "1" on the editor instead of writing on console.

Comment: If you want the read text to appear in the console window you need to write what you read to `WScript.StdOut` (see updated answer). `SendKeys` sends keystrokes to the foreground window, which is not the process spawned via `Exec`. Try `p.StdIn.Write` or `p.StdIn.WriteLine` instead.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers: `WScript.StdOut.Write c`- This gives an error **System: The handle is invalid**. Anyway, What I thought  `C:\Temp\Executable.exe -c`, would always print everything to console no matter its executed by EXEC or RUN. May be the EXEC forces the exe to run in background. Correct me if I am wrong..Thanks for the insights again.

Comment: Moreover `p.StdIn.Write 1` doesn't write anything to console.

Comment: You need to run the script with `cscript.exe`, otherwise `WScript.StdOut` won't be available.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers: ok. Thanks for the suggestion but do we have option of `WScript.StdOut.Write "{ENTER}"` to send enter keystrokes? Like as we did with `WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"`. What I have studied is Write:  _**Sends a string to an output stream**_. So I was not sure